# Fixed element appearing behind elements without z-scores.

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have 'fixed' positioned element (top navigation bar). When I scroll, a few elements on the page will still appear 'infront' of the navigation bar. None of these elements are absolutely positioned nor do they have z-score. I've also set the navigation bar's z-score to 900.

Any ideas? I'm in Chrome.

Comment: It's `z-index`, not `z-score`. If you're trying to use the latter it definitely won't work.

Comment: As @freejosh said, you need to use `z-index: 1` or higher and it will be above all other content provided no `z-index` is higher than it.